# Contextual meaning and literal meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

“Put” has several meanings.

1. To place in a specified location; set:

> She put the books on the table.

2. To cause to be in a specified condition:

> His gracious manners put me at ease.

3. To cause (one) to undergo something; subject:

> The interrogators put the prisoner to torture.

---

> I put my book on the desk.

“Put” in the sentence above has meaning 1 (To place in a specified location).

Does “put” have several meanings alone but have only one meaning if it’s used in context?

Comment: Yes. It has different meanings in different contexts, which is why several meanings are listed for it. Stating the context is how the meaning is narrowed to just one.

Comment: @Jack O’Flaherty That’s the reason why people say they need more context because a meaning varies on the context. I thought meanings are invariable.

Comment: Dude. Some words have more than one meaning. It's the same way in EVERY language.